# how to make parameter url in android json

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask

> I'm trying to fetch data from a server using this url **www.example.com/directory/** but it's not working ... it came up with this that json is not sending any action to server... so all I want is to make the url this way--  **www.example.com/directory/index.php?action=searchFood&money=50**

This is my JsonFetcher.java

```
public class JsonFetcher extends AsyncTask<Pair<String, String>, Integer, JSONObject> {

private JSONObject jsonObject;
public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(JSONObject output);
}

public JsonFetcher(AsyncResponse delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
    delegate.processFinish(jsonObject);
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(final Pair<String, String>... params) {

    int count = params.length;
    URL url = null;
    int responseCode = 0;
    jsonObject = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.example.com/directory/");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //conn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        Date date = new Date();
        String md5 = date.toString();

        //Log.e("json lock",lock);
        //Log.e("json key",md5);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            builder.appendQueryParameter(String.valueOf(params[i].first),String.valueOf(params[i].second));
        }
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // read the response
    try {
        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //conn.disconnect();
        }

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("json", total.toString());
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(total.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

}

> Is there any possibility to write in this  way `url = new URL("http://www.example/directory/index.php?action= PairActionName & PairMoney" );`   here PairActionName and PairMoney will be receiving from MainActivity

Comment: have tried this on any REST client? what you getting on REST client?

Comment: sir when i try to use on xampp it getting result and displaying in listview with this url only ("http://192.168.1.110/directory/")

Comment: after uploading on server i getting problem

Comment: how did you tried it on xampp..?

Comment: same code just use this    url = new URL("http://192.168.1.110/food_nearby/");

Comment: and getting no error no problem

Comment: why is server not receiving any action name ??

Comment: can you share the server URL with legal values?

Comment: or sir its it any possible way to ser parameter as i want above ??

Comment: can you share the server URL with legal values?

Comment: how did you tested in local server means: you were typing the whole line into browser or by using rest client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using AsyncTask for performing server operations, you shall create a encoded query string to pass arguments to the url, and write it to the URLconnection object. The example below will clear what I just said:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("param1", value1)
                                    .appendQueryParameter("param2", value2);
final String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
URL url;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try{
    url = new URL("http://www.example.com/directory/");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new   OutputStreamWriter(os,   "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(query);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    connection.connect();
}
```

On the server side you can simply retrieve the parameter values (value1) using the parameter name (param1).
Also, you can add as much parameters as you need using `.appendQueryParameter()` method.